# Generate changeset diff between current master-changelog.xml and database schema

Tags: xml, hibernate, liquibase, changeset, liquibase-hibernate

How can I generate changesetlog for the changes happened in the hbm file.
For eg: I have my database and have my hbm files in project. If I change the hbm files in the project, how can I compare the db schema and the current hbm files and generate a changesetlog for the changes.

I have searched liquibase doc, but found out that two databases can be compared but not database and the current hbm file. Is there a way to make a schema diff tool to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extension to use Hibernate configuration as a comparison side for diff https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate but haven't tried t myself so am not aware about possible issues.

Comment: Thanks, In addition to the above link this helped a lot. https://github.com/malaguna/casiopea . This is exactly what i was looking for.